# Pythonic way to filter data with overlapping dates

Tags: python, date, dictionary, readability

I have this data structure where each team has list of issues with start/end dates.

For each team, I would like to merge issues with same key and overlapping dates, where in result issue the start date will be smaller date and end date will be bigger date.

I am trying to do it with few `for` loops but I was wondering what would be the best [Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506587/2229132) way to do this.

### Update

> I want to merge only issues with same key within same team and with overlapping dates.
>
> Issues are not in chronological order.

Input:

```
{
    'Team A': [{
        'start': '11/Jul/13 1:49 PM',
        'end': '10/Oct/13 5:16 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12678'
    }, {
        'start': '3/Oct/13 10:40 AM',
        'end': '11/Nov/13 1:02 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12678'
    }],

    'Team B': [{
        'start': '5/Sep/13 3:35 PM',
        'end': '08/Nov/13 3:35 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12679'
    }, {
        'start': '19/Aug/13 5:05 PM',
        'end': '10/Sep/13 5:16 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12679'
    }, {
        'start': '09/Jul/13 9:15 AM',
        'end': '29/Jul/13 9:15 AM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12680'
    }]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    'Team A': [{
        'start': '11/Jul/13 1:49 PM',
        'end': '11/Nov/13 1:02 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12678'
    }],
    'Team B': [{
        'start': '19/Aug/13 5:05 PM',
        'end': '08/Nov/13 3:35 PM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12679'
    }, {
        'start': '09/Jul/13 9:15 AM',
        'end': '29/Jul/13 9:15 AM',
        'issue': 'KEY-12680'
    }]
}
```

To parse date, here is date format (to save you couple of minutes):

```
date_format = "%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p"
```

### Update, new test data

Input

```
d = {
"N/A": [
  {'start': '23/Jun/14 8:48 PM', 'end': '01/Aug/14 11:00 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12157'}
  ,{'start': '09/Jul/13 1:57 PM',  'end': '29/Jul/13 1:57 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '21/Aug/13 12:29 PM', 'end': '02/Dec/13 6:06 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '17/Feb/14 3:17 PM', 'end': '18/Feb/14 5:51 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '12/May/14 4:42 PM', 'end': '02/Jun/14 4:42 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '24/Jun/14 11:33 AM',  'end': '01/Aug/14 11:49 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '07/Oct/14 1:17 PM',  'end': '17/Nov/14 10:30 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '31/Mar/15 1:58 PM', 'end': '12/May/15 4:26 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '15/Jul/14 10:06 AM',  'end': '15/Sep/14 5:25 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173'}
  ,{'start': '06/Jan/15 10:46 AM',  'end': '26/Jan/15 10:46 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-20628'}
  ,{'start': '18/Nov/14 5:08 PM',  'end': '16/Feb/15 1:31 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-20628'}
  ,{'start': '02/Oct/13 12:32 PM', 'end': '21/Oct/13 5:32 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12146'}
  ,{'start': '11/Mar/14 12:08 PM', 'end': '31/Mar/14 12:08 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12681'}
  ]}
```

Output

```
{'start': '18/Nov/14 05:08 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-20628', 'end': '16/Feb/15 01:31 AM'}
{'start': '09/Jul/13 1:57 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '29/Jul/13 1:57 PM'}
{'start': '21/Aug/13 12:29 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '02/Dec/13 6:06 PM'}
{'start': '17/Feb/14 3:17 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '18/Feb/14 5:51 PM'}
{'start': '12/May/14 4:42 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '02/Jun/14 4:42 PM'}
{'start': '24/Jun/14 11:33 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '15/Sep/14 05:25 AM'}
{'start': '07/Oct/14 1:17 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '17/Nov/14 10:30 AM'}
{'start': '31/Mar/15 1:58 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12173', 'end': '12/May/15 4:26 PM'}
{'start': '11/Mar/14 12:08 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12681', 'end': '31/Mar/14 12:08 PM'}
{'start': '23/Jun/14 8:48 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12157', 'end': '01/Aug/14 11:00 PM'}
{'start': '02/Oct/13 12:32 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12146', 'end': '21/Oct/13 5:32 PM'}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at pandas?  Specifically: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: @aquavitae first time I am seeing that, but it seems like something that could be handy, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presenting a pandas solution as hinted by aquavitae in a comment, which contains the following steps:

- Read in the data from the dictionary d, that you provided into a DataFrame.
- Convert the start and end column into datetime objects.
- Sort data by keys and by start date and reset the index
- <strike>Loop over the data frame (inefficient, but I couldn't come up with something better until now)  and compare end time of current line with start time of next line, as well as if the keys are equal.</strike>
- Query pandas data frame to get the lines that overlap
- Loop over the to-be-dropped-out rows and merge the data into the corresponding overlapping row.
- Drop these rows.
- Convert back to the dictionary format.

This looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(d['N/A'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df.sort(['issue', 'start'], inplace=True)
df.index = range(len(df))
time_overlaps = df[:-1]['end'] > df[1:]['start']
same_issue = df[:-1]['issue'] == df[1:]['issue']
rows_to_drop = np.logical_and(time_overlaps, same_issue)
rows_to_drop_indices = [i+1 for i, j in enumerate(rows_to_drop) if j]
for i in rows_to_drop_indices:
    df.loc[i-1, 'end'] = df.loc[i, 'end']
df.drop(rows_to_drop_indices, inplace=True)
```

If you don't want to keep the DataFrame object and do further calculations in the format you specified in your question do:

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

EDIT: Found an efficient way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string dates to valid python datetime objects with `'%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p'` format and `datetime.strftime` function and use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sub dictionaries based on `issue` key and you can loop over the ziped groups and extract that max and min with `max` and `min` functions with a proper key function :

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
new={}

for key in d:
  for dic in [ zip(*[i.items() for i in g]) for _,g in groupby(d[key],itemgetter('issue'))] :
    temp={}
    for p,t in [zip(*tup) for tup in dic]:
      val=p[0]
      if val=='start':
        temp[val]=min(t,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p'))
      elif val=='end':
        temp[val]=max(t,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p'))
      else:
        temp[val]=t[0]
    new.setdefault(key,[]).append(temp) 


print new
```

Result :

```
{'Team A': [{'start': '11/Jul/13 1:49 PM', 'end': '11/Nov/13 1:02 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12678'}], 
 'Team B': [{'start': '19/Aug/13 5:05 PM', 'end': '08/Nov/13 3:35 PM', 'issue': 'KEY-12679'}, 
            {'start': '09/Jul/13 9:15 AM', 'end': '29/Jul/13 9:15 AM', 'issue': 'KEY-12680'}]}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've passed the correct result ? Two issues for Team A are overlapping so in result there should be only one.

Comment: @ThePavolC Yep, it just was a miss understanding! pls check out the edit!

Comment: Can you explain to me how you check if two issues with same key have overlapping start/end dates ?

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear. I'll give another sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current code, which seems to be working (it's bit tricky to check).

In my code I am using names as `epic` and `mr`, where each line in sample data is `epic` but issue key refers to `mr`.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p"

d = {"team" : [... sample data ...]}

def get_list_of_mrs(epics):
    mrs = set()
    for epic in epics:
        mrs.add(epic['issue'])
    return mrs

def is_overlap(epic1, epic2):
    start1 = datetime.strptime(epic1['start'], date_format)
    end1 = datetime.strptime(epic1['end'], date_format)
    start2 = datetime.strptime(epic2['start'], date_format)
    end2 = datetime.strptime(epic2['end'], date_format)
    return ((start1 <= end2) and (end1 >= start2))

def get_overlapping_dates(epic1, epic2):
    start1 = datetime.strptime(epic1['start'], date_format)
    end1 = datetime.strptime(epic1['end'], date_format)
    start2 = datetime.strptime(epic2['start'], date_format)
    end2 = datetime.strptime(epic2['end'], date_format)
    return (min(start1, start2), max(end1, end2))

def remove_overlaps(epics):
    filtered_epics = []
    for epic in epics:
        for temp_epic in epics:
            if temp_epic == epic:
                continue
            if epic.has_key('overlap'):
                continue
            if is_overlap(epic, temp_epic):
                temp_epic['overlap'] = True
                new_start, new_end = get_overlapping_dates(epic, temp_epic)
                epic['start'] = new_start.strftime(date_format)
                epic['end'] = new_end.strftime(date_format)

        filtered_epics.append(epic)

    filtered_epics = filter(lambda x: not x.has_key('overlap'), filtered_epics)

    return filtered_epics

for team in d:
    epics = d[team]
    epics.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['start'], date_format))
    uniq_mrs_in_team = get_list_of_mrs(epics)

    filtered_mrs = []
    for mr in uniq_mrs_in_team:
        mr_epics = filter(lambda x: x['issue'] == mr, epics)
        filtered = remove_overlaps(mr_epics)
        #print team, mr, len(mr_epics), len(filtered)
        for x_mr in mr_epics:
            #print " -",x_mr
            pass
        for x_mr in filtered:
            #print " +",x_mr
            pass
        filtered_mrs.extend(filtered)
    d[team] = filtered_mrs
```

Comment: If you think this is now answered, do you want to close this out?